# SQL View Query between multiple datastore table on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I created multiple datastore in one workspace on GeoServer using sql server and i written SQL View query to access schema table for datastore it's working fine.

```
Select Longitude, Latitude, geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' +CAST(Longitude AS CHAR(20))+ ' ' + CAST(Latitude AS CHAR(20)) + ')',4326) as geometria from dbo.objectdata
```

But i need to access another datastore of same workspace in same sql view query means correlations between multiple datastore of same workspace by using single sql view query .

so how to write query to access multiple datastore table of sqlserver?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Views have no knowledge of GeoServer's workspaces or datastores. So, you can only access other **tables** in the database in the view. This works in exactly the same way as any other database view would.